# Is this inequality true? (Inequality involving probability distribution and products)

Tags: probability, analysis

Suppose $f(z)$ is a discrete probability distribution with space $S$. Suppose $g(z),h(z)>0$ for all $z \in S$. Is it true that

$$\prod_{z \in S}{g(z)^{f(z)}}+\prod_{z \in S}{h(z)^{f(z)}} \leq \prod_{z \in S}{[g(z)+h(z)]^{f(z)}}?$$

My first impulse was to use Jensen's Inequality, but to no avail. This inequality is part of a much larger theorem I am trying to prove. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Great job with the Mathjax edits!

Comment: Thanks. It's actually an old question that no one ever answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just the superadditivity of the (generalized) geometric mean. My answer 
[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29357/an-inequality-is-it-true-if-it-is-then-how-to-prove-it/29378#29378) shows how to prove it when $f$ is a uniform distribution on $n$ points. The 
general case follows in the same way, using the [generalized AM-GM inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means#Weighted_AM.E2.80.93GM_inequality) instead of 
the usual  AM-GM inequality.

Comment: Thank you so much! You're answer allowed me to get over my mental block.

Comment: Glad to help out!