# Does this hold: $(1+\sqrt[n]{M})^n=2^n\cdot\sqrt M$

Tags: binomial-theorem

> $(1+\sqrt[n]{M})^n=2^n\cdot\sqrt M $ (TRUE/FALSE)

**My try:** Using binomial theorem, I got $$(1+\sqrt[n]{M})^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\big(\sqrt[n]{M}\big)^{n-k}=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{n!}{(n-k)!\cdot k!}\big(M^{\frac{1}{n}}\big)^{n-k}.$$

I don't know what to do next. Please help.

Comment: Try $n=1$. ${}{}{}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming $M \ge 0$ (so there are no ambiguities about branches of complex numbers), if $t = M^{1/(2n)}$ your equation says
$$ (1 + t^2)^{n} = 2^n t^n $$
and thus 
$$ 1 + t^2 = 2 t$$
which is only true for $t = 1$ (and thus $M = 1$).

Answer (score 1):

Take $M = 2$ and $n = 2$, to find that

$$(1 + \sqrt[n]{M})^n = (1 + \sqrt{2})^2 = 3 + 2\sqrt{2} \ne 4\sqrt{2} = 2^n \sqrt{M}$$

Comment: Many many thanks.

Comment: Or take $M=0$, which turns the equation into $1=0$. The equation is true when $M=1$ and $n>0$.