# Putnam Competition 2003 A2 - Question

Tags: inequality

I just wanted to have your opinions on my solution to this question. Any criticism would be welcome, especially with LaTeX formatting. I'm new to this website and still can't seem to get my LaTeX code to work on here. I assume it's not as simple as copy and pasting the code. There is a blank box or \qed symbol at the bottom, it just wasn't shown in the screen shot.

Here is an updated proof.

[image]

Comment: Could you post the actual question and your solution?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, it made me change the tags so it posted it before I could answer.

Comment: [MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this proof as far as I can see.

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar Thank you. Are the \implies arrows too frequent? I'm finding that I'm using them a lot in \align* environments. I'm new to LaTex, learning it this semester.

Comment: @Frumpy Well, in a few cases, the $\implies$ arrows are a bit redundant (such as the first three, and the last one).

Comment: You say "WLOG, we will assume ..."  But the $a_i$ and $b_i$ are given positive, so you're not assuming anything.

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar That is what I thought, do I not need any sort of arrow or implication in the beginning of each line?

Comment: @EricTowers I thought that was a problem as well early on. I will change that. Thank you.

Comment: Read it as a sentence. Would you *say* "... we are working with $n$ terms, we have: which implies the n-th root of the quantity ..."?

Comment: @EricTowers Nope that would not make sense, thank you very much.

Comment: Whoever deleted the comment saying it is not true, can you explain to me what you found that changed your mind? Interested to see what you thought.

Comment: I deleted my previous comment, and I took too mch to explain myself because I am on a cellphone. Your proof is actually right, but the $^{1/n}$ exponent in the RHS of the first two inequalities  in the proof shouldn't be there.

Comment: @chubakueno Yes you are right, they should not be there.

Comment: @Frumpy, I'm sorry, but it's still unclear to me. Could you explicitly state your actual question in your question, not just a proof?

Comment: Totally OK now!(and sorry for the typos in my previous comment, I can no longer edit them ._.)

Comment: @recursiverecursion I'm very sorry for that. When I made the post, I had the question in the picture, but I realized I put it as an answer instead of in the original post. I've updated the proof, to show the question.

Comment: I am curious, where did you find this question? Normally Putnam questions are much harder, so I think this comes from a selection of High School Olympiad level source of excercises. Am I correct? Can you share it?

Comment: @chubakueno I'm not sure. It's just a problem given to us by our professor on a project. This project was mainly focused on the AM-GM inequality and other inequalities as well as convex functions. The course is a broad course where we go over a lot of classical stuff. This problem may be easy to you, but this course is very, very difficult for the most part, conceptually.

Comment: No, I don't claim it was *easy*, I would say it is pretty fair .I just say that Putnam questions are, in general, *not fair* :) .Well, you can always answer yourself to close the topic, thank you anyways, and enjoy MSE!

Comment: @chubakueno Thank you for your help and comments ;D Have a great night/day.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29357/an-inequality-is-it-true-if-it-is-then-how-to-prove-it