# Is the geometric mean of two metrics a metric?

Tags: metric-spaces

Suppose there are two metric spaces $d_1$ and $d_2$ over the set $X$.  For $x,y \in X$, is $d_3(x,y) =\sqrt{d_1(x,y)d_2(x,y)}$ a metric space?

I am having trouble with the triangle inequality.  It is enough to show that the triangle inequality holds for $d_1(x,y)d_2(x,y)$ since the result will follow by Jensen's inequality.

Furthermore, is $(\prod_{i=1}^p d_i(x,y))^{\frac{1}{p}}$ a metric space?

Comment: How can two metrics be combined into a new metric space so that they equally contribute despite differences in scaling.  I think this is what the geometric mean does.  Would you use the p-norms?

Comment: The term you want is "metric," not "metric space." "Metric space" refers to the pair $(X, d)$ of a set and a metric on it.

Answer (score 3):

No.  For example, let $0 < \lambda < \frac12$ and set
\begin{align*}
d_1(a,b) &= \lambda
& d_2(a,b) &= 1-\lambda \\
d_1(b,c) &= 1-\lambda
& d_2(b,c) &= \lambda \\
d_1(a,c) &= 1
& d_2(a,c) &= 1
\end{align*}
(Think of $a,b,c$ as collinear points, with $b$ between $a$ and $c$.)
Then the geometric mean of distances violates the triangle inequality:
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{d_1(a,b)d_2(a,b)} &= \sqrt{\lambda(1-\lambda)} < \tfrac12 \\
\sqrt{d_1(b,c)d_2(b,c)} &= \sqrt{\lambda(1-\lambda)} < \tfrac12 \\
\sqrt{d_1(a,c)d_2(a,c)} &= 1
\end{align*}
(The inequalities are AM/GM, with strict inequality because $\lambda\ne 1-\lambda$.)

(There is [a kind of reverse inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/29357/21467).)