# What's the name of this strange inequality?

Tags: inequality, products

There is an inequality:

$$\sqrt[n]{\prod_{i = 1}^{n}{(a_i+b_i)}} \geq \sqrt[n]{\prod_{i = 1}^{n}{a_i}} + \sqrt[n]{\prod_{i = 1}^{n}{b_i}}$$

which I even don't know its name. I'd like to have an ask of its name and usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [Mahler's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahler%27s_inequality).  We had it here in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/29357) (see also the linked questions), and it was question A2 on the 2003 Putnam, so you can find some proofs in [Kedlaya's archive](http://kskedlaya.org/putnam-archive/).

As for its usage: It is sometimes used to prove the Brunn-Minkowski inequality (of which it is a special case, as Umberto P. noted).  In that proof, one first proves this inequality, deduces Brunn-Minkowski for the case when both bodies are axis-aligned boxes, uses a clever induction to extend to finite unions of axis-aligned boxes, and then completes the proof by approximation.  That proof, which is due to Ohmann, can be found in §8.2 of Gruber's *Convex and Discrete Geometry*.

Answer (score 2):

It is a special case of the *Brunn-Minkowski Theorem*. It isn't strange at all; it is a rather useful inequality in measure theory.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I really need an explore on Wikipedia instead of Chinese math textbooks.