# Show that $1+(x_1x_2...x_n)^{\frac{1}{n}} \leq [(1+x_1)(1+x_2)...(1+x_n)]^{\frac{1}{n}}$

Tags: real-analysis, problem-solving

Show that $$1+(x_1x_2...x_n)^{\frac{1}{n}} \leq [(1+x_1)(1+x_2)...(1+x_n)]^{\frac{1}{n}}, \forall x_i \geq 0, \ i = 1,2,3...,n$$

So, I have to make this function something like this:

$$f(t_1x_1+t_2x_2+...t_nx_n) \leq t_1f(x_1)+t_2f(x_2)...+t_nf(x_n)$$ Also, I need to choose an $f(x)$ such that the inequality holds and $f''(x) > 0$ to show that this is a convex.

Ok, so it is getting really difficult for me as I don't understand what to choose as $t_i$ and what to choose as $f(x)$. All I can do is this:

$$1+[e^{\log(x_1x_2...x_3)^{\frac{1}{n}}}] \leq e^{\log[(1+x_1)(1+x_2)...(1+x_n)]^{\frac{1}{n}}}$$

Maybe I can choose $f(x) = \log(x)$, but that'd give me $f''(x) < 0.$ Can anyone please help me figure out what $t_i$ and $f(x)$ should be in order to make it a convex? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you could use induction on $n$ and then just have to prove the case for $n=2$.

Comment: @bgins, I think I could. But, I am trying to learn it in the way as above.

Comment: Maybe try $f(x)=\log(1+x)$, $t_i=1$ and deal with $f$ being concave in stead of convex (so $-f$ would be convex).

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29357/prove-a-1b-11-n-cdotsa-nb-n1-n-ge-lefta-1-cdots-a-n-right1-n

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may take $g(t)=\log(1+e^t)$. We have:
$$ g''(t) = \frac{e^t}{(1+e^t)^2} $$
hence $g$ is a convex function. Let $x_i=e^{t_i}$. Jensen's inequality hence gives:

$$ \log\left(1+\exp\left(\frac{t_1+\ldots+t_n}{n}\right)\right)\leq \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\log(1+e^{t_i})$$
and by exponentiating the previous line:
$$ 1+\left(x_1\cdot\ldots\cdot x_n\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}\leq\left((1+x_1)\cdot\ldots\cdot(1+x_n)\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}$$
i.e. the super-additivity of the geometric mean, follows.

Answer (score 1):

You can invoke Maclaurin's Inequality (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maclaurin%27s_inequality).  Let $S_k$ be the average symmetric sum of degree $k$ for $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n$ and $k=0,1,2,\ldots,n$.  Then, $\sqrt[k]{S_k}\geq \sqrt[n]{S_n}$ for every $k$.  Note also that $1=S_0=S_1^0$ (where we take $0^0$ to be $1$), and $S_1\geq\sqrt[k]{S_k}$ for all positive $k$.  Now, since $\prod_{i=0}^n\,\left(1+x_i\right)=\sum_{k=0}^n\,\binom{n}{k}\,S_k$, we get
$$\prod_{i=0}^n\,\left(1+x_i\right) \geq \sum_{k=0}^n\,\binom{n}{k}\,\left(\sqrt[n]{S_n}\right)^k=\left(1+\sqrt[n]{S_n}\right)^n\,.$$
Also, you can show that
$$\prod_{i=0}^n\,\left(1+x_i\right) \leq \sum_{k=0}^n\,\binom{n}{k}\,S_1^k=\left(1+S_1\right)^n\,.$$
Hence,
$$1+\sqrt[n]{\prod_{i=1}^n\,x_i}\leq\sqrt[n]{\prod_{i=1}^n\,\left(1+x_i\right)}\leq 1+\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n\,x_i}{n}\,.$$
However, you can also achieve the inequalities above by applying AM-GM too.

Answer (score 0):

$F=(1+x_1)(1+x_2)(1+x_3).....(1+x_n)=1+\sum_{i} x_i+\sum_i{\sum_j}_{i\ne j} x_i x_j+\sum_i\sum_j{\sum_k}_{(i\ne=j\ne k)} x_i x_j x_k+....$
By AM-GM, we get

$F\ge 1+{n \choose 1} (x_1x_2x_3...x_n)^{1/n}+ {n \choose 2} (x_1x_2x_3...x_n)^{2/n}+{n \choose 3} (x_1x_2x_3...x_n)^{3/n}+....=(1+(x_1,x_2x_3...x_n)^{1/n}]^n.$